# x-axis <g> tag transform not transitioning

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have two x-axes on a horizontal bar chart, and when they are created they are both given a transform that translates them vertically (`.attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + (height - 5) + ')');`). When a data point is removed, the chart shrinks, which changes the height variable, which obviously changes the transform. If I try to add a transition, nothing happens. It doesn't just not animate, but it doesn't even set the transform. Without the animation it at least sets the transform (just way too early, so it looks really weird as everything else is shrinking).

Here's the relevant code:

```
chart.select('.x-axis.top').transition().duration(1500)
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + (height - 5) + ')');
```

Again, if I simply remove `.transition().duration(1500)`, the transform at least still changes.

### Update

While modifying [Lars Kotthoff's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1172002/lars-kotthoff) jsfiddle to match the code I've been working on, I figured out what the problem was. It was basically this:

```
svg.select('.x-axis')
    .transition().duration(1500).attr("transform", "translate(0,100)");
svg.select('.x-axis')
    .transition().duration(1500).call(axis);
```

In order to animate the ticks of the axes, I was running `.call(axis)` after the data updated. With that code snippet it was obvious I should try to tack `.call(axis)` onto the end of the first call, and of course after that it worked.

This example is obviously a bit contrived; in the code I've been working on there's some logic (that's basically just turning off some transitions when the chart is first initialized) that seperates the two functions.

I considered answering my own question, but while the fix is pretty quick and obvious, I still think that it's weird that the second call should prevent the first one from working correctly. So the question still stands, I suppose, as to *why* this doesn't seem to work, instead of just how to fix it. Here's the [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uf4cm1os/) that shows the problem.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: Nope, no errors. I debugged and compared  the object before and after chaining in the transition, and they both point to the same object. Though, the `parentNode` attribute was missing on the transitioned object.

Comment: Works for me https://jsfiddle.net/jyLv96rL/

Comment: I [updated the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uf4cm1os/) to include a timeout, and another call to `.call(axis)` in order to animate the ticks themselves. That's when it stopped working. Though after that I figured out I just needed to put that call onto the end of the transform call. It's still weird to me that it doesn't work as I originally wrote it, though, so I've updated my question.

Comment: You're overwriting the first transition with the second one -- you can simply chain the two calls. Also, there's a `.delay()` parameter and you don't need `setTimeout()` https://jsfiddle.net/uf4cm1os/1/